# Pandas count specific values in a column after groupby and put into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to count a specific value within a multicolumn group `['a', 'b', 'c']` in a column `'u'` and apply its value to a new column `[cnt_u1, cnt_u2]` no matter what value in `'u'`. This is the input df:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([['u1', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
                       ['u1', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
                       ['', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
                       ['', 'a1', 'b1', 'c2'],
                       ['u2', 'a1', 'b1', 'c2'],
                       ['', 'a1', 'b1', 'c2'],
                       ['', 'a2', 'b1', 'c3'],
                       ['u2', 'a2', 'b1', 'c1'],
                       ['u2', 'a2', 'b1', 'c1'],
                       ['u2', 'a2', 'b1', 'c1'],
                       ['', 'a2', 'b1', 'c1'],
                       ['u3', 'a2', 'b3', 'c2']
                       ], columns=['u', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Below you can find the desired output. Please note that I'm interested only is specific set of values `u1, u2`, i.e. `u3` is skipped.

```
     u   a   b   c cnt_u1 cnt_u2
0   u1  a1  b1  c1     2     0
1   u1  a1  b1  c1     2     0
2       a1  b1  c1     2     0
3       a1  b1  c2     0     1
4   u2  a1  b1  c2     0     1
5       a1  b1  c2     0     1
6       a2  b1  c3     0     0
7   u2  a2  b1  c1     3     0
8   u2  a2  b1  c1     3     0
9   u2  a2  b1  c1     3     0
10      a2  b1  c1     3     0
11  u3  a2  b3  c2     0     0
```

What I managed to achieve is where count should be applied:

```
for s in ('u1', 'u2'):
    df[f'x_{s}'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['u'].transform(lambda x: (x == s).any())
     u   a   b   c   x_u1   x_u2
0   u1  a1  b1  c1   True  False
1   u1  a1  b1  c1   True  False
2       a1  b1  c1   True  False
3       a1  b1  c2  False   True
4   u2  a1  b1  c2  False   True
5       a1  b1  c2  False   True
6       a2  b1  c3  False  False
7   u2  a2  b1  c1  False   True
8   u2  a2  b1  c1  False   True
9   u2  a2  b1  c1  False   True
10      a2  b1  c1  False   True
11  u3  a2  b3  c2  False  False
```

How get the count for each group where value in `'u'` is equal to 'u1' and put into `'cnt_u1'` column (the `'u2'` respectively)? I don't claim the transform/any approach is the best, I'm open to anything that works as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need `sum` for count `True`s values:

```
for s in ('u1', 'u2'):
    df[f'x_{s}'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['u'].transform(lambda x: (x == s).sum())
```

Or you can assign new column and use only `sum`:

```
for s in ('u1', 'u2'):
    df[f'x_{s}'] = df.assign(u = (df.u == s).astype(int)).groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['u'].transform('sum')
```

---

```
print (df)
     u   a   b   c  x_u1  x_u2
0   u1  a1  b1  c1     2     0
1   u1  a1  b1  c1     2     0
2       a1  b1  c1     2     0
3       a1  b1  c2     0     1
4   u2  a1  b1  c2     0     1
5       a1  b1  c2     0     1
6       a2  b1  c3     0     0
7   u2  a2  b1  c1     0     3
8   u2  a2  b1  c1     0     3
9   u2  a2  b1  c1     0     3
10      a2  b1  c1     0     3
11  u3  a2  b3  c2     0     0
```